# Object-to-Object Transformation Diagram

Tags: mapping, uml, diagram

I'm writing some code to map one complex data structure into another, and would like to create a diagram of the mappings beforehand.  I'd like to show which fields map to each other, and what types of transformations are applied to the data.

Is there a standard (UML?) diagram for this type of work?  Are there any good tools out there for creating diagrams for this?

The data structures I'm working with are about 3-4 objects deep, but fairly simple.  There's no database access required during the mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard diagram to do this, really.  You can use classes, keywords/stereotype, and dependency/trace lines, but it is very partial.  For example, mapping attributes in diagram form is not possible.  Additionally, many-to-one situations might be hard to show.  Finally completeness of the mapping or the depth of mapping in the tree might be hard.  If it is simple you can if you want.  I would use what you are comfortable with.